# RegEx expression to hit only words with a-z and no aumlats

Tags: php, regex

Can you help me out with this one? I have a list of words like this:

```
sachbearbeiter/-in
referent/-in
anlagenführer/-in
it-projektleiter/-in
```

I want to select only:

```
sachbearbeiter/-in
referent/-in
```

This is my current regex: `([a-z]+)/-(in)`

The problem is it hits all even the ones with `-` and with `ü`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use anchors to match the word you want:

```
^([a-z]+)/-(in)$
^---- Here ----^
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/WdDi3G/1)**

Update: for your comment, if you want to accept aumlats you can use unicode flag with `\w` like this:

```
^(\w+)/-(in)$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/WdDi3G/2)**

Comment: @Federico Pizza I have a follow up question though if I decided to accept german aumlats what should be added?

Comment: @MickyZ you can turn `u` (unicode) flag and change `[a-z]+` by `\w+`, that way you will match those characters. Check **[this example](https://regex101.com/r/WdDi3G/2)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify beginning & end  of string so that it can match exact chars

change your regex to

```
^([a-z]+)/-(in)$

^ -> stands for beginning of string
$-> for end of string
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current regex i.e. `([a-z]+)/-(in)` does escape the `/` character and also trying to look into substrings that matches the pattern, so it'll show each of them.

Regex should be : `^([a-z]+)\/-(in)` i.e. it should start with only small case alphabets with escaped `/`